# How to delete a child and a parent object in the same batch class?

Tags: batch, scheduled-apex

I have a situation, where I need to delete both parent and child log files. I need a batch file, as the number of records is large, and the delete is on a weekly basis.

OFC - I can write a second apex batch, and execute it, but I prefer not to.

I am able to write the code to delete the child records with ease:

```
global class deleteOldMassLogs implements Database.Batchable<sObject> { // created to bulk delete records - use with care!

global final String QueryChild;
global final String QueryParent;

global deleteOldMassLogs() {
    QueryChild = 'select id from dca_mass_action__Mass_Action_Log__c where createddate < Date.Today().addDays(-7) and dca_mass_action__Parent_Log__c <> null';
//        QueryParent = 'select id from dca_mass_action__Mass_Action_Log__c where createddate < Date.Today().addDays(-7)';
}

global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
    return Database.getQueryLocator(QueryChild);
}

global void execute
    ( Database.BatchableContext bc 
    , List<dca_mass_action__Mass_Action_Log__c> scope
    ) {
    delete scope;
}

global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc) {}
}
```

Once all the child records are deleted, how can I delete the parent as well? in the same batch?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same batch, just remember that you should check if there are any remaining children left. Something like this should work:

```
Set<Id> parentIds = new Set<Id>();
for(dca_mass_action__Mass_Action_Log__c record: scope) {
  parentIds.add(record.dca_mass_action__Parent_Log__c);
}
delete scope;
delete [SELECT Id 
  FROM dca_mass_action__Parent_Log__c 
  WHERE Id IN :parentIds AND 
   Id NOT IN (
     SELECT dca_mass_action__Parent_Log__c FROM dca_mass_action__Mass_Action_Log__c
   )
];
```

I guessed the parent object name, so you may need to make appropriate changes.